# Failed to start gunicorn.service: Unit is not loaded properly: Bad message

Tags: django, service, gunicorn

I'm having difficulty configuring gunicorn. So far, I have pulled my django code onto the server, created a virtualenv for python3.6, installed django gunicorn psycop2, using pip3, and that's all fine.

I can run the django development server and see my unstyled site and have successfully posted to the database via the admin site, so that is all working. I then started it directly using:

```
gunicorn django_version.wsgi:application --bind 10.88.58.95:80
```

and again was able to see my unstyled site. I've also tried:

```
/srv/pcc_django/django_env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/srv/pcc_django/django_version/django_version.sock django_version.wsgi:application
```

and this started with no errors. So my next step was to write a .service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/srv/pcc_django
ExecStart=/srv/pcc_django/django_env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/srv/pcc_django/django_version/django_version.sock django_version.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and trying:

```
systemctl start gunicorn.service
```

I get the above error message, and it says to do:

```
systemctl status gunicorn.service
```

and there's the following message:

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: error (Reason: Bad message)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2019-10-17 08:39:02 UTC; 3h 16min ago
 Main PID: 29080 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 16 16:24:08 pcc-home-page.novalocal gunicorn[29080]: [2019-10-16 16:24:08 +0000] [29085] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29085
Oct 16 16:24:08 pcc-home-page.novalocal gunicorn[29080]: [2019-10-16 16:24:08 +0000] [29086] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29086
Oct 17 08:39:02 pcc-home-page.novalocal systemd[1]: Stopping gunicorn daemon...
Oct 17 08:39:02 pcc-home-page.novalocal gunicorn[29080]: [2019-10-17 08:39:02 +0000] [29084] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 29084)
Oct 17 08:39:02 pcc-home-page.novalocal gunicorn[29080]: [2019-10-17 08:39:02 +0000] [29080] [INFO] Handling signal: term
Oct 17 08:39:02 pcc-home-page.novalocal gunicorn[29080]: [2019-10-17 08:39:02 +0000] [29085] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 29085)
Oct 17 08:39:02 pcc-home-page.novalocal gunicorn[29080]: [2019-10-17 08:39:02 +0000] [29086] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 29086)
Oct 17 08:39:02 pcc-home-page.novalocal gunicorn[29080]: [2019-10-17 08:39:02 +0000] [29080] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Oct 17 08:39:02 pcc-home-page.novalocal systemd[1]: Stopped gunicorn daemon.
Oct 17 08:39:14 pcc-home-page.novalocal systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:12] Missing '='.
```

but there is something strange going on, because if I do:

```
date +%H:%M:%S.%N
```

I get the following timestamp:

```
11.57.13.124995238
```

So I'm not sure that this message relates to gunicorn service not starting correctly. What have I missed that is preventing gunicorn from starting as a service?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that I did not have a gunicorn.socket file and this was in the service file as Required. Adding the following file into the same folder as the service file:

```
/etc/systemd/system/
```

gunicorn.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Fixed part one of the problems, then correcting the .sock file location in the .service file (above in original post) and finally I also added a shebang at the top of the service file. The changes are in line 1 at the top and in the middle of line 11 in the [Service] section:

```
#!/bin/sh    

[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/srv/pcc_django
ExecStart=/srv/pcc_django/django_env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock django_version.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Also make sure the the .sock file is consistently named I have called it "gunicorn.socket" so in the paths it is called "gunicorn.sock" in most of the tutorials, they have it named as:

```
project_name.sock
```

and put it in the project root folder, as well as people mentioning that it is a security issue to put it in with your code, I just found that it became confusing to know what the file was called compared to where it was. So calling it gunicorn.socket just makes more sense to me and it's easy to see on a CLI as it does not get confused with file paths.